# What does "fit" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> The swimsuit top featured a knotted front design while the bottoms were designed with a high-waisted **fit**. ([source](https://www.marieclaire.com/fashion/a21267735/kourtney-kardashian-brown-bikini/))

I thought it meant "a matching piece" but can't be sure because it appears to have some fashion-specific meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Here it means how the clothes were designed and made to fit on the body.

> A slim fit jacket

Would be a suit that was designed for a slender person (for the same chest size, the slim fit jacket has a narrower waist.)

In your case the swimsuit is designed to fit high on the waist (and so probably expose more of the leg)

Comment: ...or exposes less of the midriff.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, "high-waisted fit" means the clothing is worn higher on their waist.